# Como ficou a relação entre Web Api e Asp.NET MVC no Asp.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Nos `ASP.NET 4.6` ou inferior existia diferenças entre Web Api e Asp.Net MVC. O `controller`, por exemlo, pode herdar de `controller` ou de `ApiController`. Porém, com a chegada do `Asp.Net 5` não terá mas essa separação, a diferença será entre `AddMVC` e `AddWebApiConventions` nos serviços, como dito [neste artigo](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/asp/arquivos-de-configuracoes-asp-net-5/?trace=1519021197&source=single).

Realmente foi unificado os dois e se essa é a única diferença?

Comment: Conseguiu esclarecer sua duvida?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Eu havia esquecido dessa pergunta, sorry. Eu criei ela com caráter informativo e eu mesmo iria colocar uma resposta, mas esqueci. Se quiser responder também, ajudaria a ter mais conteúdo sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme informação no blog do Scott Haselman, os *controllers* no *ASP Core* foram unificados, então não existem mais as classes `Controller` ou `ApiController`, há somente um `Controller` que retorna `JSON` ou `Views` com HTML e possui uma estrutura única para funcionalidades como rotas, etc...

O método `services.AddWebApiConventions();` deve ser utilizado para facilitar a portabilidade de versões anteriores da Web Api, este método faz parte do pacote `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` que contém uma classe `ApiController`, esta classe possui uma estrutura que **imita** a Web Api de versões anteriores.

O método `services.AddMvc();` adiciona a estrutura básica do MVC para a versão atual do ASP Core.

Fontes: 
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/webapi.html
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringAMinimalWebAPIWithASPNETCore.aspx